# How to achieve our own custom deployment UI for wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, clickonce

Recently I have installed Oculus Store app and it has customized UI for deployment.I am trying to achieve this but didn't find any resources regarding UI for deployment. Someone please provide resources for how to achieve customized UI for deployment.

Are there any deployment technologies that can provide this customization.?

Thanks.

Sample images: 
[image: Start page]

[image: Choosing folder to install]

[image: Progress page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a webinstaller. You can achive this in almost every installer. I do know that this design is reproduceable with Advanced Installer.

Comment: could you provide any links for resources. that would be very helpful.

Comment: This is the theme: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/surface-screen-shot.html and here is the reference: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ui-themes.html

Comment: Ohkk thanks :) . But it is not for free right. Any free libraries allows me to do that ?

Comment: With hard work yes. Inno or Nulsoft installer are free.